# discord.py run the command on users who have specific roles

Tags: discord.py

I was creating a command that sends a private message to multiple users who have specific roles.
To do this, I created a currently numeric category where, depending on the category that is chosen, it must send dm to users if they have specific roles.

Here is my problem is that I can not get the roles read what could I do?

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dmall(ctx, number, *, message):
    guild = discord.Guild
    if number == "1":
        if guild.get_role(role_id=690951634183782461):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(message)
                    print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"{member.name} non ha ricevuto il messaggio perchè i suoi messaggi privati sono chiusi.")
        else:
            return
        elif number == "2":
        if get(guild.roles, name='Triumvirato'):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(message)
                    print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"{member.name} non ha ricevuto il messaggio perchè i suoi messaggi privati sono chiusi.")
        elif get(guild.roles, name='Co-Triumvirato'):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(message)
                    print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"{member.name} non ha ricevuto il messaggio perchè i suoi messaggi privati sono chiusi.")
        else:
            return
    elif number == "3":
        if get(guild.roles, name='Triumvirato'):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(message)
                    print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"{member.name} non ha ricevuto il messaggio perchè i suoi messaggi privati sono chiusi.")
        elif get(guild.roles, name='Co-Triumvirato'):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(message)
                    print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"{member.name} non ha ricevuto il messaggio perchè i suoi messaggi privati sono chiusi.")
        elif get(guild.roles, name='Presidente ad Interim del LMII'):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(message)
                    print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"{member.name} non ha ricevuto il messaggio perchè i suoi messaggi privati sono chiusi.")
        else:
            return
    return
```

Comment: You want to be able to use the command to pick the number of roles, the message to be sent, and wich roles you are sending the message as well? Or if you pick 1 you are sure it is for Triumvirato members, pick 2 and you are sure it is for Co-Triumvirato and Triumvirato members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the role members list using `discord.Role.members`, instead of `ctx.guild.members` that returns the members list of the entire guild, iterate through it sending messages for everyone in this list

```
@commands.command()
async def dmall(ctx, number, *, message):
    if number == '1':
        specific_role = ctx.guild.get_role(690951634183782461)
        sr_members = specific_role.members
        for member in sr_members:
            await member.send(message)

    elif number == '2':
        specific_role = ctx.guild.get_role(second_role_id)
        sr_members = specific_role.members
        for member in sr_members:
            await member.send(message)
```

And so on for more roles.

.

.

If you need the list of all roles, you may use `ctx.guild.roles` and use the `number` parameter more efficiently as the index of the list returned by `ctx.guild.roles`

By this way you type in *!dmall 2 hi* and it will do the same thing the above code was doing, but now it is going to use the third role id in `ctx.guild.roles`

```
@commands.command()
async def dmall(ctx, num, *, message):
    sr_members = ctx.guild.roles[num].members
    for member in sr_members:
        await member.send(message)
```

You will be able to call any role you want, you just need to know its index.

Need to check their indexes?

```
@commands.command()
async def info(ctx, *, role:discord.Role):
    print(ctx.guild.roles.index(role))
```

Comment: and if I need more roles, do I create different for for each role?

Comment: I thought that was why you were using the `number` parameter. I updated the answer for that sittuation where you wanna reference to multiple roles using the same command

Comment: maybe I explained myself wrong.
number I'm using it as a tentative since I'll replace it with category. I updated the wrong code I did so that I can better explain what I would like to do. Now as I understand the second code you wrote should count roles but I don't understand it very well.

Comment: Assuming you listed all roles in your server in your code, and your bot has a bot role called 'Bot', a loop like this `for role in ctx.guild.roles: print(role.name)` should return in this order: @everyone,
Bot,
Co - Triumvirato,
Presidente ad Interim del LMII,
Triumvirato.


Wich means the index of 'Triumvirato' would be 4, that is how you count roles. I updated the answer